# Get sum of more than one table columns with a single query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a main table **hotel** and its sub tables **hotel_food**, **hotel_extras**, **hotel_room** with the reference Id **hotel**,

And now I want to get the sum of price column in each table (hotel_food, hotel_extras, hotel_room) for each hotels.

Now I am using like this

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT id FROM hotel WHERE id = '.$hotel.'");
if($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $food_result = $db->query("SELECT sum(price) FROM hotel_food WHERE hotel_id = '".$row['id']."'");
   $room_result = $db->query("SELECT sum(price) FROM hotel_room WHERE hotel_id = '".$row['id']."'");
   $extras_result = $db->query("SELECT sum(price) FROM hotel_extras WHERE hotel_id = '".$row['id']."'");
}
```

Is there any way to get the sum of all tables prices like totalFoodPrice, totalRoomPrice,totalExtrasPrice with a single query

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the subqueries like this :

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT id, 
   (SELECT sum(price) FROM hotel_food WHERE hotel_id = h.id) TotalFoodPrice,
   (SELECT sum(price) FROM hotel_room WHERE hotel_id = h.id) TotalRoomPrice,
   (SELECT sum(price) FROM hotel_extras WHERE hotel_id = h.id) TotalExtraPrice
FROM hotel h WHERE id = '.$hotel.'");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT sum(price) AS totalFoodPrice FROM hotel_food WHERE hotel_id = 1,
 SELECT sum(price) AS totalRoomPrice FROM hotel_room WHERE hotel_id = 1,
 SELECT sum(price) AS totalExtrasPrice FROM hotel_extras WHERE hotel_id = 1
) temp
```